# How to rename a file name with referenace of csv file

Tags: python-2.7

I have a files like this.

1.stream0106.wav

2.stream0205.wav

3.steram0304.wav

I need to rename "01" in a file name as "_C" & "06" as "_LFE1" Like this.This new names I have in csv file like below.

[image: This is my example csv file has new names]

Can you please guuide me for this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you guide me for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want the "01" to be replaced or appended. The csv titles make it confusing.

I would first make the csv file start in column A and row 1 to make reading it in easier for you.

If you are appending names this should work

```
import os
import csv

# Assuming files are just in current directory
wav_files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.wav')]
with open('your_file.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    mappings = [row.strip().split(',' ) for row in csv_file.readlines()[1:]]

for f in wav_files:
    for digit, name in mappings:
        if f[:-4].endswith(digit):
            new_name = f.replace(digit,name)
            os.rename(f, new_name)
            break
```

**EDIT**

```
Old Name,New Name
00,_0
01,_C
02,_L
03,_R
04,_Ls
05,_Rs
06,_LFE1
07,_Cs
```

This can be achieved by just having them in excel starting at Col A and Row 1

Comment: Cam you share example image for how i want to put a csv file.

Comment: "01" should be renamed as "_C". I have updated my csv file above